# defaults does not exist for com.microsoft.VSCode

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, default

I have VSCode installed, and I'm wanting to set the ApplePressAndHoldEnabled boolean to false.  When I try:

`>defaults read com.microsoft.VSCode
2019-11-29 14:13:42.734 defaults[644:2080008]
Domain com.microsoft.VSCode does not exist`

If I do:

`>defaults domain`, I see com.microsoft.com in the list.  If I do:
`>defaults read -app VSCode`, I get:
2019-11-29 14:33:44.649 defaults[945:2091878] Couldn't find an application named "VSCode"; defaults unchanged

I see a com.microsoft.VSCode.plist in ~/Library/Preferences.

Any help/ideas?

Comment: I have defaults for VSCode, try opening a folder and try again. Or try to create one by doing `defaults write com.microsoft.VSCode ApplePressAndHoldEnabled true`

Comment: My bad, that command is missing a -bool flag, it should be `defaults write com.microsoft.VSCode ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool true`

Comment: I've tried that, and every time I get `2019-12-01 12:59:21.247 defaults[25330:2399959] Could not write domain com.microsoft.VSCode; exiting`  Note that this is happening on a new account that I added on my mac.  The new user has admin access.  If I go back to the user that installed VSCode and run the command it works, so its something about permissions, but I can't figure it out :-\